# How to identify by a trigger if any insert update delete function operation performed in any table of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a database in which I want to make a centralized trigger; if any database table is hit with an insert, update or delete operation, then this trigger should be executed and column values that are inserted, updated or deleted from that operation should be saved in my own table by the help of trigger.

I have seen `fn_dblog` function in SQL Server but it does not return column values which are affected. I need to save that column values also which are going to be inserted or updated.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/ I think this is the better place to ask this question.

Comment: This isn't as straight forward as you think. It is rather complex. This is really too broad for SO. But [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+audit+any+dml+statement) is a great place to start.

Comment: You don't want a trigger (and there is no way to assign a DML trigger to all the tables anyway), you want something like [Change Data Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server) or [Change Tracking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server) depending on version/edition & whether you need to keep all before/after data. On SQL Server 2016 or better, check out [Temporal Tables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables).

Comment: You **cannot** apply a trigger to multiple tables - triggers are **per table** only

Comment: Temporal tables are not available in SQL SERVER 2014